# Can you invest in a shop multiple times to keep increasing the vendor gold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can you invest in a shop multiple times to keep increasing the vendor gold?

The speechcraft perk is rather vague about investing multiple times, but I assume it is a 1 time deal for that merchant.

If anyone has tried it, let me know if you can just keep doing it to get more permanent vendor gold.

Comment: No. Just the once (if it is anything like Oblivion). 
I can't 100% confirm, but... yeah..

Comment: Invest in the Riverwood Trader. He will have 12,000 gold from that point forward. Enjoy never worrying about gold again.

Comment: Lucan Valerius has since been patched. He now get only gets an extra 500 gold when you invest in the Trader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only upgrade a merchant one time with the Investor perk (Speech 70).  However you can get another perk, Master Trader (Speech 100) which gives every trader in the world an additional 1000 gold.
*[Source: Game and Official Strategy Guide]*

Comment: Didn't even notice the 100 Speech perk. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Does _Master Trader_ give them 1000 gold each **day**, or only as a once off?

Comment: I heard before 1.9 if you invest lucan in th Riverwood trader it adds 10,000 gold to the store.

Comment: Their normal pool of trading gold goes up by 1000. It still resets every 48 in game hours as normal.

Answer (score 7):

Just one time. I've tested this by myself. Remember not to steal the money after investing. You will lose the investment and also you can't invest again.

I made this mistake, but perhaps Bethesda will fix this so that I could invest again...

Comment: Good to know about the stealing gold breaking the investment. I'm marking the other one as the answer, only because Cloudancer mentioned a perk I hadn't seen. Your answer is appreciated (and also correct) and the steal bug is noteworthy.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I've read about it and may well try it when the time comes on my next full play through. Similar to how stealing invested gold back negates the investment(at the initial time of investment), reverse pickpocketing more gold than just the investment 500 makes the merchant have even more gold to barter with every 48 in game hours. There is a 16 bit limit of 32,767 beyond which it glitches out, but you could safely push the gold to around 30,000. May only be able to add 4000 or so at a time at most so as not to fail and get caught.

Answer (score 1):

I have invested about 20,000 in the War Maiden shop in Whiterun. I guess it's just a glitch, but I've been able to continue investing.